# nixpkgs nix-env -u how to stick to an attribute path

Tags: nixos

Same as question [here](https://github.com/madjar/nox/issues/94)

I installed ungoogled-chromium using nox on my arch linux (manjaro) daemon nix system. It works great, but when doing updates `nix-env -u` it tries to update ungoogled-chromium to normal chromium [I think it has to do with ungoogled-choromium being version 81.x and normal chromium being 83.x] how to I get it to stay on the ungoogled-chromium releases?

`nox chromium` output:

```
1 chromium-83.0.4103.61 (nixpkgs.chromium)
    An open source web browser from Google
20 chromium-81.0.4044.122 (nixpkgs.ungoogled-chromium)
    An open source web browser from Google, with dependencies on Google web services removed
```

Comment: Would adding in the package by full path, `nixpkgs.ungoogled-chromium` (I am not sure what it is called) into my `~/.config/nixpkgs/config.nix` make it stick to the correct source? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57555786/nix-install-unstable-packages-using-nixpkgs-config-nix

Answer (score 0):

It is a current bug in the system. There is a partial work around though https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/3283